# mySQL .NET Connector, GridView not updating

Tags: c#, mysql, gridview

- Visual Studion 2012 Update 3 with mySQL .NET Connector 6.6.5.0
- I cannot get a GridView to post back any updated data

My GridView is configured as:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mysqlConn %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mysqlConn.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Name, Unit, Price FROM product" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE product SET Name = ?, Unit = ?, Price = ? WHERE ID = ?">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String"  Direction="Input" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Unit" Type="String"  Direction="Input" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Single"  Direction="Input" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int64"  Direction="Input" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The grid displays the list of products fine. However when I select Edit in the grid view and change a value and then click Update the resulting change is not posted back to the database. What am I doing wrong with my Update statement or parameters?

All pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing:

```
DataKeyNames="ID"
```

as part of the GridView definition which was preventing the UPDATE from happening.

Answer (score 0):

please use GridView1.DataBind();
then gridview  will bind with new data. 
please refer this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx

Comment: DataBind() is only required when you are filling the dataset yourself is my understanding. As the grid is currently displaying the data I would say that the problem is elsewhere and not a DataBind() call.